# how to open images in a listview in a dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

i have an asp.net listview that shows images and i would like it that when the user clicks on an images it opens in a jquery dialog.

here is my list view:

```
        <div id="images">
```

>
                
                    
                    
                
                
                    
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            
                                No data was returned.

```
                </td>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td4" runat="server" style="">
                    <a href='<%# Eval("img") %>' class="PhotosHref">
                    <img id="photoAlbumPhotos" src='<%# Eval("img") %>' alt="Image Not Found" class="Photos" />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="Table1" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                    <tr ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                        <td ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div style="">
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td5" runat="server" style="">
                    id:
                    <asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                    <br />
                    img:
                    <asp:Label ID="imgLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("img") %>' />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </div>
```

how can i do this , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following link. Hope this will definitely give you an idea,

http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2011/ajax/jquery-dialog-box-tutorial

You can see the full demo code also in the following url,

http://www.ajaxonomy.com/files/dialogdemo.txt

Comment: i got it working but when i click on an image it opens in a dialog and disappear from the listview